# android ImageView is not Working

Tags: android

I want to renew ImageView whenever set pixel of Bitmap class. but ImageView is not working. I already use ui thread. what should i do?
this is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView img;
    DisplayMetrics dm;
    Bitmap bit;
    int x = 1, y = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

        bit = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, RGB_565);

            for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
                for(int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
                    bit.setPixel(i,j, Color.WHITE);
            }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true) {
                    bit.setPixel(x++, y++, Color.BLACK);

                    img.setImageBitmap(bit);
                    img.invalidate();
                    try{
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    }catch (Exception e){

                    }
                }
            }
        });


    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you use While TRUE?

Comment: use `ImageView.post()` method instead of `runOnUiThread()` method

Comment: @oskarkl I want to change continuously.

Comment: @Jimit Patel I change my code img.post. but, it does not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use postDelayed into your `ImageView.post()` method. Here I have done this on my machine. Plus don't use `while(true)` stop it when your pixels ends.

```
img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);

        bit = Bitmap.createBitmap(300, 400, RGB_565);
        for(int i = 0; i < 300; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < 400; j++)
                bit.setPixel(i,j, Color.WHITE);
        }
        img.setImageBitmap(bit);


        img.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                bit.setPixel(x, y, Color.BLACK);
                img.setImageBitmap(bit);
                if(++x < 300 && ++y < 400){
                    img.postDelayed(this, 100);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update View using [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html).

```
img.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

            }
        });
```